# countable,uncountable noun

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is difference between these two sentences and when can I use each one

1. There has been **a fierce debate** over the way the war was fought
2. There has been **fierce debate** over the way the war was fought

Comment: If you consider the debate over the way the war was fought to be a single event, use the article. If, on the other hand, you consider it a condition with many individual events, don't use the article, because you're treating it as a mass noun.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question [words that are both countable and uncountable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552057/words-that-are-both-countable-and-uncountable).